# How to give SettingsActivity in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, preferenceactivity

Nooby question once again here. I did a lot of research to add a 'Settings' row in Navigation Drawer to go to my SettingsActivity. But failed to get a good working solution. Someone please help me out.

```
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.tab_11) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.tab_22) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.tab_33) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.setting_nav) {
                           // What to add here ?
                        }
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: no answer for this question? :/

Comment: Exactly specking I didn't got your que...it is unclear...what I understand is u need to link your settingActivity to the navigation drawer is that so? If it is correct 1. Where is that setting_nav is that a tab?2.is it placed on the actionbar ?3. Where r u using that setting_nav

Comment: @Amaresh the id setting_nav is to show the settings button in Navigation Drawer. So it is now blank. So there is no activity now. My question is , How can i link the SettingsActivity to the button Settings in Navigation Drawer. My codes make the question clear by telling where to add the codes, now i need is what codes to add there?

Comment: Use intent to call the activity u want...

Comment: Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), settingActivity.class);
startActivity(nextIntent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS is the one u r asking for rite?

[image]

```js
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.tab_11) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.tab_22) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.tab_33) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.setting_nav) {
                           Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), settingActivity.class);
                           startActivity(nextIntent);
                        }
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: the intent needs `nextIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` or it will crash

Comment: @EpicPandaForce   `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);` What about this?